# Codeigniter Google Map How to search by city name?

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

I am using a *Google Map for Codeigniter* library, which can be found here:

https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library

But I can't figure out how to search by city name with this library. I didn't find anything inside the documentation and examples.

Is it possible to search by city names with this library? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want to use Places Autocomplete to find location(city) names and move the viewport of the map to that location.

If that is what you want, you have a working example here:

http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/placesautocomplete

Comment: Dear I have seen this before but could you provide how to implement this textbox what function or which parameters should I pass to find the location which I need. I think it does not find all the places such google map does find.